# How do I write a correct twitter web intent?

Tags: twitter

I want to embed a tweet button on a webpage with a text an url but no original referrer. I've been trying with this:

```
<a class="twitter-share-button"
  href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world" url="www.something.com">
Tweet</a>
```

But I each time end up with the name and url of my web page in the tweet. What's the correct syntax for what I want to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `url` parameter should be part of the Twitter intent (like `text`):

```html
<a class="twitter-share-button"
  href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world&url=www.something.com">
Tweet</a>
```

Check the [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/overview) for web intents.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks Andy. I found the documentation not really very clear. For one thing, it lacks examples.